# Remotely download a file from an external link to my server - download stops prematurely

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have a page set where I enter the url of an file and I have my server download that file and save it into a folder on my server. The issue is that I dont know how to download a file to my server. I have tried both of the following methods, and they both didn't work.

This one throws an error about a failed open stream:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/file.zip';
$enc = urlencode($url);
$dir = "/downloads/file.zip";
$raw = file_get_contents($enc);
file_put_contents($dir, $raw);
```

This one works but I only get 18kb out of a 270kb file: ( I have tried to increase the timeout)

```
set_time_limit(0);

$url = 'http://www.eample.com/file.zip';
$fp = fopen ('/downloads/file.zip', 'w+');

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FILE           => $fp,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 50,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)'
    ));

$results = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
 {
  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
 }
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but I have had to change the user agent to something common in the past to get this to work. Also, make sure the url that you use isn't just one that redirects to the real file that you want.

Comment: @gpojd what do you mean. For example, when I put the url into my browser it doesn't take me to a site, it just starts the download. Is that an issue.

Comment: Add `curl_close($ch);` at the end. *Maybe* it helps. Also after it, place `fflush($fp); fclose($fp);` - check return values as well, see the manual for these functions. BTW `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,` makes no sense. Also you can tell curl to return the content-length, check it with `curl_get_info` (or similar) and compare with size of the file.

Comment: Then ignore the second part of my comment. Try setting the user agent in curl or in file_get_contents to one that a common browser would send. Some sites block uncommon user agents that a bot might use.

Comment: @gpojd Okay I changed it to my real user agent and it is still not full downloading the file.

Comment: Can you try it using curl or wget from the command line on the same server? What about on your PC? One of those might help to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This one throws an error about a failed open stream:
>
> ```
> ...
> $enc = urlencode($url);
> ...
> ```

I'd say no wonder, because you don't need to "urlencode" that url which is already properly encoded. Try:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/file.zip';
$file = "/downloads/file.zip";
$src = fopen($url, 'r');
$dest = fopen($file, 'w');
echo stream_copy_to_stream($src, $dest) . " bytes copied.\n";
```

See [`stream_copy_to_stream`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/stream_copy_to_stream). If you need to set more HTTP thingies like user-agent etc. use the [HTTP Context Options<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php).

Comment: This worked like a charm. I changed the original url which led to an apk file to a regular jpg picture and it worked. I guess the other site was denying my request. Thank you.

Comment: This is also much better because you don't need to store the (potentially large file) in a variable only to save it. You can also register callbacks on streams so you can find out more what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Will this system use bandwidth from the network I use to call the script or just from my server's network?

Comment: depends on where www.example.com is