# Download file through a server to user

Tags: php, curl, download

There is a file located on a server. Lets call it "Movie".

My site's users need to downoad this movie, but the movie can only be downloaded by my website's IP.

Is there a way to download Movie to my server and from there to the user?

I can do that by "put_content" but I need the client to download the file WHILE my server downloads it.

Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that proceeding like this will keep your server's connection to the client active for the duration of the download/streaming etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [standard wrappers PHP offers<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/wrappers.php) and combine that with [`stream_copy_to_stream`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/stream_copy_to_stream):

Example / [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JdkGAY):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://example.com/some.url';
$src = fopen($url, 'r');
$dest = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$bytesCopied = stream_copy_to_stream($src, $dest);
```

Related (couldn't find a better duplicate so far):

- [Remotely download a file from an external link to my server - download stops prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9730285/367456)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `readfile` function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php